# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно?

Tags: пунктуация, падежи

Индивидуальный предприниматель Попов Иван Иванович, в лице Попова Ивана Ивановича, действующИЙ(ЕГО) на основании свидетельства...

Comment: действующИЙ или действующЕГО

Answer (score 2):

Данная формулировка выглядит абсурдной и с логической, и с юридической точки зрения.

Правильно, например, так:

*Индивидуальный предприниматель Попов Иван Иванович, в лице Сергеева Сергея Сергеевича, действующего на основании доверенности № 1 от 01.01.2016, именуемый в дальнейшем «Покупатель»...*

*Индивидуальный предприниматель Попов Иван Иванович, именуемый в дальнейшем «Покупатель»...*

[Социальная правовая консультация](https://socpravo.ru/pravilnaya-storona-dogovora/)

> ...индивидуальный предприниматель и гражданин — это одно и то же лицо. Поэтому и действует индивидуальный предприниматель сам.
>
> Если представлять интересы предпринимателя будет иное физическое или юридическое лицо, то представителя необходимо указывать, ссылаясь на доверенность или иной документ с полномочиями.
>
> ...дополнять правильную полную конструкцию всякими свидетельствами и иными завитушками можно, но говорить это будет просто о неграмотности специалиста как юриста.

Comment: Спасибо большое за исчерпывающий ответ.